# What event should I use to something when I select any text in a RichTextBox in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to perform some action when some text is selected from a `RichTextBox`. So in what event of the `RichTextBox` should I write my logic?

I'm designing a notepad. I have one `Menustrip` and in the `Menustrip` I have Copy, Paste, Undo and Redo option. I want these options to be visible to the users only when a user selects any text in the `RichTextBox`.

I've tried it in many events but haven't succeeded so far.
I've tried in `RichTextBox` the `Mousecapturechanged` event and `Toolstripmenu menu active event`.

I am using C#.

Kindly help.

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please edit your question!

Comment: How about `SelectionChanged` ?

Comment: let me try then .. I'll comment once I try

Comment: no brother.. Didn't work . I want these buttons to be enabled when ever i select some text in richtextbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to subscribe to the [`MouseUp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the `RichTextBox` and within the event handler, check if the length of the selected text is greater than 0 like this:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0)
    {
        // Show the Copy, Paste, Cut Buttons...
    }
}
```

This is because the [`SelectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event fires whenever the selection is changed and so will not even let you select text properly.

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro I realized later that selectionchanged was no good :)

Comment: Change the previous question should be a bad thing?

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro Two answers here are quite different and even the selectionchange could come handy on some occasions. There's no harm in adding two answers as long as they are not similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`SelectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event which:

> Occurs when the selection of text within the control has changed.

MSDN Link - [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

This event would be ideal for what you aim to achieve.

Now you also need to use this properly. This event will fire even if you type something. So you have to verify that something is selected like this:

```
private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length > 1)
    {
        // Show the Copy, Paste, Cut Buttons...
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro I've already tried this one.But it's not working .. As the definition says SelectionChanged event occurs when text within the control has changed.. But i want When i select something then only the event should raise.. If u're not getting me then see notepad how copy cut button behaving

Comment: @chikun see the update use the code I provided after attaching it to the event

Comment: it worked like a charm .. i was using richtextbox1.text instead of richtextbox1.SelectedText .. thanx man thanx a lot

Comment: @chikun Please have a look at my other answer. It is better and I would request you to accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectionChanged` event and check if the cursor has changed or a part of text has been selected.

```
private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (richTextBox1.SelectionLength < 2) return;
    //Show the menu
 }
```